# What industry regulations protect the privacy of DNA results in the US? (UK, or EU wanted as well)

Tags: dna, research-tools

I am writing computer software that allows users to learn more about their own DNA and (optionally) allow some of that data to be used for research purposes.

I'm very concerned about a future/theoretical situation in which an insurance company uses that DNA data to disqualify someone on the basis of pre-existing conditions.

**Question**

- What privacy regulations exist that would assure users that there is no insurance risk in a collecting information about one's own DNA? (Primarily interested in the USA, but UK and EU would be valuable)
- Outside of legal regulations, what should users look for when shopping among providers? (for quality, scope of services provided, etc)

Comment: There might be different regulations in different parts of the world. Maybe you want to specify a country/area.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology.

Comment: That might be a question for [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/). I am voting to close for the same reason than canadianer

Comment: While the subject is biology based, ethics and laws are not... so I am voting for closure as well.